# Malformed config.xml when using phonegap and <application> Tag

Tags: android, coldfusion, phonegap

Trying to Generate PhoneGap Build using Adobe ColdFusion Builder 2016.

When I include:

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="IntentTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
<data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>

        </activity>

<activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
<intent-filter></intent-filter>

</activity>

</application>
```

I get this error at `build.phonegap.com`

> Error - Malformed config.xml - You can fix this here.

I have tried other `<application>` tag and the same result.

Comment: Where is the end of the application tag?

Comment: I would run it through an external parser and see if it gives a better message

Comment: I edited the code to show the end </application> tag.

Comment: I have run it through an external parser to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[Phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/)

In the above document, it describes how to exempt code from the xml parse on phonegap.

> you can contribute xml directly to your Android Manifest and iOS Property List >files, via the config-file element (beta feature).

For Android, you have to include this in the header.

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap = 
"http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android = 
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id = "com.yourapp" 
version = "1.0.0">
```

Then in the code

```
  <config-file platform="android"  parent="./application" mode="add">


    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="IntentTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
<data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>

        </activity>

<activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
<intent-filter></intent-filter>

   </activity>

    </application>

    </config-file>
```

When I generated the Build on build.phonegap.com the  tag and all related code were included in the AndroidManifold.xml